# Combine the result of 2 tables Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to combine the result of 2 tables into 1 A and B :

```
$A = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { get-wmiobject Win32_Product  |  where-Object{ $_.name -like "*Google*" } | select PackageName ,PSComputerName  }
$B = gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture ,PSComputerName
```

**Result A :**

```
PackageName                            PSComputerName
-----------                            --------------
googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi COMPUTER1
```

**Result B :**

```
osarchitecture PSComputerName
-------------- --------------
64-bit         COMPUTER1
```

**The desired output :**

```
PackageName                            PSComputerName      osarchitecture
-----------                            --------------      --------------
googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi COMPUTER1           64-bit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a `[PSCustomObject]`.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$a |Join $b -on PSComputerName`

Comment: your 2nd line is getting info from the LOCAL system. why don't you put both calls into one `Invoke-Command` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, two of them shown below:

### Using `Select-Object`

Using `Select-Object`, we can create a new object by stitching the output from one command onto the output from another:

```
$OSArch = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product |Where-Object Name -like "*Google*" |Select-Object PackageName,@{Name='OSArchitecture';Expression={$OSArch}},PSComputerName
```

---

### Create a `[pscustomobject]`

Another popular option is by using the `[pscustomobject]` syntax introduced in PowerShell 3.0:

```
$OSArch = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product |Where-Object Name -like "*Google*" |ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        PackageName = $_.PackageName
        OSArchitecture = $OSArch
        PSComputerName = $_.PSComputerName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanksss a looooot Mathias (y)

Comment: @OussLa you're welcome! Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)